# The method or operation is not implemented WPF Behavior

Tags: wpf, infragistics, behavior

I just ran into a problem I can't seem to find answers to, and I haven't the slightest idea where it's coming from.

The exception is popping up in run time, after the plugin containing the XamDataGrid loading starts, saying:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

I can post some code if needed, but while debugging, the error is happening before the "`OnAttached`" of the behavior.

I am using visual studio, nothing else.

Comment: Did you install a new version of infragistics or did you update the existing? If yes then you have to update your references to the correct version of infragistics controlls

Comment: i did all those. this happened after some refactoring, and i can't seem to find what is causing it.

Comment: This can be because you have some themes or styles from infragistics which are referenced in some dlls which you don't have reference. If you have no idea where to start, then I would suggest to reference all infragistics dlls and remove one by one to find out which one you need.

Comment: i did that, i referenced all, and the exception is still happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem, the error message wasn't related to it in any way.

There was a small warning hidden in the build log:

> "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent
>   assembly that could not be resolved. These reference conflicts are
>   listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed."

Set the verbosity level to "Diagnostic" not detailed(detailed doesn't help at all), and found that I made a mistake with the references, in one of the projects System.Windows.Interactivity was version 4.5, in the other 4.0.

I've set them both to 4.0, and the problem is gone.

ps. I've set them to 4.5 before and got this error

> "Cannot add instance of type XamDataGrid to a collection of type
>   'BehaviorCollection'. Only items of type 'T' are allowed."